# Importing huge .sql script file (30GB) with only inserts

Tags: python, sql-server, powershell, import

I need to import some SQL scripts generated in SSMS (generate scripts). These scripts only contain INSERTS.

So far I managed to import almost everything using DbUp (https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). My problem is with larger files, in this case I have 2, one 2GB and one 30GB.

- The 2GB I imported using BigSqlRunner (https://github.com/kevinly1989/BigSqlRunner)
- The 30GB one I've tried everything (PowerShell, split, etc..) and I'm not succeeding, it always gives a memory error and I can't find anything to help me split the file into multiples small files...

I'm asking for your help if you know of a better way or a solution for this.

The goal is to migrate data from one database (PRODUCTION) to the another empty database (PRODUCTION but not used) and I am doing it through generate scripts (SSMS) and then execute the scripts on the target database (for security due to it being production and I don't want to be reading it line by line while importing the data to the target database).

I am open to other solutions that may exist such as SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services), Python, PowerShell, C#, etc... but I have to be careful not to impact the production database when reading the data from the tables.

Comment: from sqlserver to another, why not do a simple backup and restore ?  with simple t-sql, fast, no impact, no other tools needed

Comment: If it were up to me I would do it but it can't be done that way and I'm not the one in charge...

Comment: Know your tools and what they can handle. If your tools cannot handle extremely large files, then make smaller ones. No one knows what alternatives are available to you based on cost, experience, timeliness, etc. And tool recommendations are off-topic in any event.

Comment: *"but it can't be done "* can you elaborate? Why can't it be done? Creating backups is a fundamental part of on premises instances.

Comment: you already have reader and view definition access. you just need the db_backupoperator role.

Comment: By `split`, do you mean UNIX/Linux/Gnu split? Is the file full of `INSERT` statements? I am surprised that would not work. Can you copy/paste, as text, the `powershell` code you tried and describe in what way(s) it did "not succeed?" Please copy/paste the error message into the question as well.

Comment: @Larnu I can’t restore a complete database in production, I have to open a request and I’m only a SQL Developer

Comment: If you have a 30GiB file full of insert statements, in one batch with no `GO` separators, I'm not surprised you're getting out-of-memory errors. The client computer has to load that 30GiB in a single batch, transmit it over the network and SQL Server then has to parse it and execute it in a single 30GiB batch. If you can't use SQL Server backup/restore operations will they allow you to use BCP and/or bulk load operations?

Comment: @lit no, I’m talking about split the file in windows with some code but I can’t simply break the file into multiple files because inside I have multiple INSERTS and I can’t break the SQL statement.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning ahhh yes I don’t have the GO I have exported without it! So if I use the GO inside the 30gb file, the code (powershell, dbup, etc) will use the file in batches instead of all??

Comment: Not automatically. `GO` isn't a standard T-SQL keyword, it's only recognized by SQL Server Management Studio and sqlcmd. If you were using PowerShell you'd have to write code that splits the file on the `GO` keywords and sends each batch to SQL Server for parsing/execution separately.

Answer (score 0):

To update I managed to solve it through SSIS, I made a source and a destination connection and used the source query with WITH(NOLOCK), it's running and already half way through. It's not the fastest but it's working. Thank you all for your help.